# Haskell: How do I create a function that allows none, one or two Applicatives?

Tags: haskell, applicative, alternative-functor

Control.Applicative.optional allows to handle zero or one Applicatives.
many & some allow for 0 or more, or 1 or more, respectively.
I'd like to create a function that handles zero, one or two, specifically.
The signature could be as for many/some, that is

```
zeroOneOrTwo :: Alternative f => f a -> f [a]
```

I feel this should be pretty straightforward, but I've been playing around with it for a while and cannot make it work.  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The truly dumb way is `zot f = sequenceA [f, f] <|> sequenceA [f] <|> sequenceA []`.

Answer (score 8):

How about this one:

```
zeroOneOrTwo :: Alternative f => f a -> f [a]
zeroOneOrTwo a = go (2 :: Int)
  where
    go n
      | n > 0 = ((:) <$> a <*> go (n - 1)) <|> pure []
      | otherwise = pure []
```

Comment: I'd rather flip the two cases: `go 0 = pure []; go n = ...`

Comment: I'd keep it this way – checking `n > 0` prevents infinite descent at invalid input – and _not_ wrap `go 2` but export it directly as `atMost :: Int -> f a -> f [a]`.

Comment: Thank you @redneb, that's exactly what I was trying for, but somehow couldn't make it work.  Many thanks.

Comment: @leftaroundabout yes, that's what I will go for, indeed my ultimate goal - but I couldn't even make the 0..2 case work initially.  Though is there any reason we couldn't or shouldn't use Natural rather than Int to eliminate at least one class of error?

Comment: Reuse library functions for `go`! `upTo n a = asum [replicateA m a | m <- [0..n]]`. Now if only `replicateA` were a library function... (why isn't it??)

Comment: @DanielWagner, `Control.Monad.replicateM` only needs an `Applicative` now.

Comment: @DanielWagner, won't that sum-of-products approach be inefficient for some important `Alternative` instances?

Comment: @DanielWagner, it's certainly no good for `Maybe`, which (without optimization, at least) will case match on the same sequences over and over until it locates the failure point.

Comment: @dfeuer I conclude the exact opposite, that it's very good for `Maybe`: `asum (replicateM 0 undefined : undefined) = Just []`.

Answer (score 5):

If you're going to the trouble of restricting the result like that, you might as well make its type reflect that.

```
data ZOT a = Zero | One a | Two a a

form :: a -> Maybe a -> ZOT a
form a Nothing = One a
form a (Just b) = Two a b

zeroOneOrTwo :: Alternative f => f a -> f (ZOT a)
zeroOneOrTwo a = (form <$> a <*> optional a) <|> pure Zero
```

What if you want up to three? Or up to four? You can cover all such cases at once with a couple language extensions.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs #-}

data Nat = Z | S Nat

data Natty n where
  Zy :: Natty 'Z
  Sy :: Natty n -> Natty ('S n)

data AtMost n a where
  Nil :: AtMost n a
  Cons :: a -> AtMost n a -> AtMost ('S n) a

atMost :: Alternative f => Natty n -> f a -> f (AtMost n a)
atMost Zy _ = pure Nil
atMost (Sy n) a = (Cons <$> a <*> atMost n a) <|> pure Nil
```

---

What if you don't want to use any fancy extensions? Well, it won't look quite so pretty, but you can still do it if you like, taking a page from Ralf Hinze's "Numerical Representations as Higher-Order Nested Datatypes".

```
data Z a = Z deriving (Show)
data S f a = Nil | Cons a (f a) deriving (Show)

class AtMost g where
  atMost :: Alternative f => f a -> f (g a)

instance AtMost Z where
  atMost _ = pure Z
instance AtMost g => (AtMost (S g)) where
  atMost m = (Cons <$> m <*> atMost m) <|> pure Nil
```

Note that there are now two different ways to construct an empty result, `Z` and `Nil`, with different types. `Z` is used when the result is as large as requested, while `Nil` is used when it comes up short.

```
*AtMost> atMost (Just 3) :: Maybe ((S (S (S Z))) Int)
Just (Cons 3 (Cons 3 (Cons 3 Z)))

*AtMost> atMost Nothing :: Maybe ((S (S (S Z))) Int)
Just Nil

*AtMost> atMost undefined :: Maybe (Z Int)
Just Z
```

Comment: That's possible, but IMO it's more reasonable to stay with lists as the result and make the maximum length an extra parameter.

Comment: Huh! _I_ surpressed the impetus to remark that it could also be done with a full dependent-type approach, but it was kind of clear that this would turn up anyway...

Comment: Thank you very much @dfeuer.  I had briefly considered this, and was even going to mention it in the question - but given that I couldn't get the list-based version working, this was clearly beyond my noggin.  But now you have given me something to cogitate on and learn how it works.  That's much appreciated.

Comment: Am i right that if i wanted `atMost` return type to be `f [a]`, i wouldn't need `data AtMost`?

Comment: @arrowd, redneb's answer shows how to do that. My aim was to allow the consumer of the result to use the known size bound to avoid unreachable errors and such.

Comment: @dfeuer I meant, i want to retain bounds in the type, but have the result type to lose this information. But i've already figured this out.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, you can get away without the fancy stuff if you really want; see my latest edit.